# Django ManyToOne relations

Tags: django, django-models, django-1.8

Please help me with relation ManyToOne. I tried many different variants but it wasn't worked for me. Exception:

> IntegrityError at /admin/gallery/gallery/add/ duplicate key value
>   violates unique constraint "gallery_gallery_galleryCategories_id_key"
>   DETAIL:  Key ("galleryCategories_id")=(1) already exists.

And my models code:

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime
from imagekit.models import ImageSpecField
from imagekit.processors import ResizeToFill


class Gallery(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Title', null=True)
    galleryCategories = models.ForeignKey('GalleryCategories', verbose_name='Category', unique=False) #this line

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title


class GalleryCategories(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Title', null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

Help me, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to run `./manage.py makemigrations` and `./manage.py migrate`.
I think you were using `unique=True` and after you changed it to `False` without migrating your database.

Comment: I removed migrations dir from gallery dir, and run `./manage.py makemigrations` and `./manage.py migrate`. But problem still reproduce( I my initial code u can saw `unique=False`

Comment: You must not delete your migrations dir, because the migraitons framework will find that the table exists and will not apply changes.

Comment: The easiest way for you now to re-create your database and don't delete your migrations folders in future.

Comment: Yes, it's work. When I created gallery and galleryCategory models first time, I forgot param `unique=False`. But when I added this property after migrate this didn't work(for me). Now I drop this two table from db and try migrand again and my models WORK. Thanx.

Comment: I'm glad to help you, but you can remove `unique=False`, this is the default behaviour otherwise there's no difference between `ForeignKey` and `OneToOneField`. A one-to-one relationship. Conceptually, this is similar to a ForeignKey with unique=True, but the “reverse” side of the relation will directly return a single object.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#onetoonefield